# Could someone explain bounties for me?

Tags: support, bounty

[LINK](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/28764/2-year-old-started-resisting-going-anywhere)

I am honestly asking so that I understand. I think the bounty was awarded to the actual best answer -- so no problem and no complaint.

I have 4 upvotes, the awarded answer has 2. It does not show as the accepted answer. Community awarded the bounty.

I thought 'Community' was not a person. If it is a robot, how did a 4 UV answer 'lose' to a 2 UV answer?

Perhaps mods are 'Community'? If so, I agree with their choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things like this it's always worth checking on Meta.SE first, as the bounty system is part of the whole SE network.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139534/154443) says it all:

> Community doesn't add bounties. Both of the bounties that are currently attributed to Community were actually added by a user who has since been deleted. When the user was deleted the bounty was transfered to Community's ownership.

Comment: Thanks, I did not understand that Community was a person in this case. I did read about bounties, but obviously in the wrong place. The award makes perfect sense to me as I would have accepted that answer if I were the OP.

Comment: Note this answer actually does not apply in this particular instance.  The account used to post this bounty has not been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

What happened is that the person who posted the bounty never awarded it.

Per the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties):

> Bounties expire after seven days. You will receive several
>   notifications a few days before this happens.
>
> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period
>   ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top
>   voted answer **posted after** the bounty start, provided it has a score of
>   at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation
>   will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be
>   lost forever.

Note the part that I emphasized.  The bounty was started on February first, after you had already posted your answer.  The answer that was awarded half of the 100 point bounty was posted on February 2nd.

The person who posted the original bounty had a period of time during which they could award the bounty.  They did not (presumably because they're quitting the site), so the auto-award clause kicked in.

Note that the person who posted the bounty has **not** deleted their account.  The offering of the bounty still shows their name in the edit history.  It is only the awarding of the bounty that shows Community, and that is because the user didn't actually award it.

Comment: thanks, it went the right way, even though I did not understand!